# Understanding jQuery UI (basic): How to set the value of a slider

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

The real problem is that I just have not learned enough basic JavaScript yet. I'm learning but it's got me all messed up right now.

So I figure this is really simple but I can't put my head around it yet.

I had some code that I finally got working just great and I understood it well enough, then I got help (and it's works great too) but I don't understand the way you select an object and change it's value using jQuery.

Here is the new code (working great):

.html

```
<div style="display:block;margin:100px auto;padding:0 8%">
    <input type="text" id="amount3" style="border:0 none" class="slider_value">

    <div id="slider3" class="slider_container" data-value="0" data-min="0" data-max="15" data-steps="1"></div>

    <div class="steps">
        <?php
        for ($i=0, $t=15; $i<=$t ; $i++) {
            echo '<span class="tick" style="left:'.(100/$t*$i).'%;';
            if ($i==ceil($t/2)) echo 'font-weight:bold;font-size:medium;';
            echo '">|<br>'.$i.'</span>';
        }
        ?>
    </div>
</div>
```

.js

```
$(function(){
    var value, step, min, max, input;

    $('.slider_container').each(function(){
        input = $(this).prev('.slider_value');
        value = $(this).data('value');
        step  = $(this).data('steps');
        min   = $(this).data('min');
        max   = $(this).data('max');

        $(this).slider({
            value: value, 
            min: min, 
            max: max, 
            step: step,
            slide: function(event, ui) {
                $(this).prev('.slider_value').val(ui.value);
            }
        });

        input.val($(this).slider("value"));
    });
});
```

With a pure html5 slider it's easy to change the slider value: `document.getElementById("slider3").value = '5';` however this does not work with the new code and I can't figure it out.

I have a number of sliders with different IDs. I have an onchange event on a field that fires an AJAX sql search and returns data that I then use to set all the sliders on the page. This all works fine until I added jQuery UI... But only because I don't understand how to select the slider I want to change.

Comment: http://api.jqueryui.com/slider/#method-value See second example.

Comment: Yes I read that before posting here. I know it's simple but what does $( ".selector" ) need to be? How do I identify it? or better yet, what's the correct syntax for my code above?

Comment: I guess I'm asking if .selector is an element ID? document.getElementById("slider3").value = '5'; works with html5 but what selector do I use in my code above?

Comment: `$('#slider3').slider('value', 5);` See https://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turned out not to be so hard:

```
$(p2).slider({
  value: 0,
  slide: function(event, ui) {
    $(this).prev('.slider_value').val(ui.value); }
});
```